# Unable to predict using bart() {BayesTree}

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression, bart

I used bart function from BayesTree library to build a model on my training data. It fits my training data very well. However, I'm unable to predict for the test set and check its performance.

`predict(model, test)
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "bart"`

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been solved using bartMachine() {bartMachine} which has an associated predict function (predict.bartMachine)